# Compare Dates and find out weather First date is greater from second

Tags: php

Date1=23-3-2013

Date2=26-3-2013

How to compare above both date such as
If Date2 >= Date1
Echo greater them equal to

Else

Echo not greater them equal to

Here greater does not means mathematically greater

Comment: [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `strtotime($date)`
Therefore, you would have something like:

```
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)){
    echo Date 2 is greater than date 1;
}else{
    echo Date 1 is greater or equal than Date 2;
 }
```